# How to design a stateless REST Login with 2 Factor Authentication (2FA)?

Tags: rest, authentication, stateless

I'm struggling with the concept of how to design a stateless RESTful authentication API with multi-factor authentication.

Almost by definition, the need of a 2FA requires multiple states; logging in with a username/password, then submitting a "code" (either a TOTP, SMS-code, answer to a verification question, etc).  This further implies a finite-state-machine (FSM) of some sort.

As far as I can tell, the only options which exist in order to maintain a stateless mechanism are:

1. the client must transmit some state information (ex: current FSM state) when submitting data to transition to the next state,
2. the state must be persisted on the server side,
3. the client must transmit ALL data at every request which allowed it to reach the current state

Obviously transmitting ALL data is nonsensical.  So this would imply either transmitting state information (opaque or otherwise) in the request or maintaining state on the server.

Or is there some other technique that I am missing?

Comment: i would look from an architectural perspective at how AWS structures 2FA in its Cognito authentication product. Also, I know that from a consumption perspective, each next layer of activity with the API requires that I pass in a combination of data. so, by the end, I'm sending things like the session token, my phone code, plus my original auth object, etc. You may find something useful there

Comment: @Eric B. Have you found an answer for this. If yes, can you please let me know as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NickDiv I posted the solution I came up with.  Please let me know if this is clear or if you need additional information.

Comment: @EricB. Thanks a lot Eric for your answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm adding the solution I came up with in case it is beneficial for someone else in the future.  Please note that in this case, PVQ stands for "Personal Validation Question" (ie: Knowledge-Based-Authentication).

At the end, I designed my login endpoint to require:

- Authorization header (which is a 2FA token) : `Authorization: authType=”PVQ”
  token=”<tokenid>”`
- username
- password

If the `Authorization` header is missing, the endpoint returns a 401 and sets a `WWW-Authenticate` header, indicating that a 2FA token (ie: Authorization header) is required to login.  param could be PVQ, SMS, TOTP, etc (based on the user's configuration)

```
WWW-Authenticate : authType="PVQ"
```

If the client receives a 401/WWW-Authenticate response, it is its responsibility to call the 2FA endpoints:

- challenge/get (receive a challenge token)

  - Client: sends username/password
  - Server: Responds with an ID, and either

    - a question (PVQ),
    - or just sends sends an SMS code via 3rd party SMS provider
- challenge/verify (receive the 2FA Token needed for the `Authorization` header)

  - Client: sends

    - ID received in the `challenge/get`
    - username/password
    - response to the challenge (ie: text answer to a PVQ, or SMS code, or TOTP code)
  - Server: returns

    - 2FA token value

The client can now call the login endpoint with the required: username/password/Authentication token.

In the end, there is not "state" per say that the client returns to the server, but the tradeoff for this, is that the username/password combination must be sent to every request for the 2FA subsystem.

On the server side, there is some state information stored in the DB in the context of the SMS code or PVQ question that was sent to the user, as well as an ephemeral Authentication 2FA token (single use, and fixed TTL).

Comment: Eric, thanks for this post, this is a nice design. Why do you need to send username\/password for `challenge/verify` request? If I am not mistaken and `ID` stands for single `challenge` and `ID` is a random identifier, than providing `ID` should be enough for second step of challenge.

Comment: @user1921819 I don't recall my use case exactly, but I believe I needed it to authenticate to my 2FA system, to in order to recover/validate the response the challenge (I think the username/pwd was used to retrieve some salting information).  But theoretically, otherwise, I wouldn't need the username/password and the ID would have been sufficient.